# Deploying and SQL Server CE file along with Win Forms Application In VS 2010

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-ce

I have created a Winforms application using visual studio 2010 in C#.

I created a local SQL Server CE file (`.sdf`) and added it to my project. Initially, I had a problem as during the course of my application, I was writing data to the database and when I checked in the server explorer, the database always seemed empty but the data values were correct.

I then realized, that the database gets copied to the bin and when I checked that database file, I could see all my data over there.

My connection string is currently

```
conn = new SqlCeConnection("Data Source =KHDASurvey.sdf");
```

Now the problem arises when I want to deploy the project to a client's machine. I do not want them to have to install any files or any environments of any sort and I want all the files that are needed to be deployed.

I came across two ways to deploy a project:

the one click method outlined here: [here](http://robindotnet.wordpress.com/2010/02/28/how-to-deploy-the-sqlserver-compact-edition-software-locally/)

then another one using setup project [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=USfQzZX-ytQ)

I like the set up project option so when I run it the user can select where the application
exe file will reside.

I add the files and content to the setup project and then I built it. I create an installer and then I execute it.

When the application is created, I see the `.exe` and I even see a `.sdf` file residing in the
same location.

But the application data will only remain while the application is running, then after that I get empty values as it seems nothing is either getting written, read or both. As shown
before, my connection string is set so that it reads from the db file locally.

I have really looked all over for several solutions, I did not find one which completely
explains it. I saw something about altering the connection string in app.config but I am
not really using it in the code, the connection string that is.

Please give me some suggestions or point me in the right direction.

Thank You

Comment: I have some ideas here: http://erikej.blogspot.dk/2013/10/sql-server-compact-4-desktop-app-with.html

Comment: I have followed quite a bit of it now. I am getting stuck on the bit Generate the LINQ to SQL DataContext, I downloaded the SQL Server Compact Toolbox and installed it but I am unsure of how to open the wizard shown there

Comment: Go To Tools, SQL Server Compact Toolbox, or start it from Server Explorer (must have VS Pro or higher). Also, using this feature requires SQL Server Compact 3.5 SP2 to be installed on your PC

Comment: thank you very much, I followed the steps of your tutorial and FINALLY from 9 am in the morning till 10 p.m now, I have something. Now I need to apply this to actual application. I have a question, do you have any tutorials on how to use LINQ to push data to the database. I am a bit new to it so it would be helpful.

Comment: I have done everything, I have managed to make the connection work in 3.5. But the frustrating part is, I am trying to write new data but it never seems to update. Yesterday for a bit it was updating when I was writing the results to console but if I was looking at the SQL Compact Toolbox, it still shows old data values. So I switched my laptop off and came back today morning to work on it, now even in the console it is showing old data values, nothing seems to work when I am updating.

Comment: Also, in the article I notice, when adding the database, it says mark it as "copy always." Is this how to do it when we need to actually make updates and insert to the database? Wouldn't it get overwritten? Should I use copy if newer instead as it seems to give appropriate results for now.

Comment: For LINQ to SQL advice, there is plenty on the internet. During developemnt, use a full path to the database to avoid losing data.

Comment: I have a question, during deployment, is it possible to be able to specify where the .sdf file would be stored ?

Comment: I describe that in my blog post !?

Comment: Thank you so much Erik, everything works, now there is one problem. When i create the setup file, I install it on my machine (same which i developed in), it works perfect, on my colleagues machine also it works well.

If i input it on a random machine(tried it on 2), the exe launches for 2,3 seconds and exits. I do not see anything, I just monitor processes from task manager and it shows my application starts and then just quits. Important point is me and my friends machine had VS 2010 in it while these did not.

Comment: Continued: On checking event viewer I see System.IO.FileNotFound exception and an issue with KERNELLBASE.DLL. What should I do ?